# Code for the next symbol

Tags: arrows

What is the latex code for the symbol in the picture? (That arrow with $~$)

[image]

Comment: Just `$\tilde{\leftarrow}$`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the symbol supposed to mean?

Comment: Was going to suggest [How to look up a symbol or identify a letter from a math alphabet or other character? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-letter-from-a-math-alphabet-or-other-chara/21#21) but this doesn't seem to be a single symbol so it doesn't really help. // that doesn't quite look right, but neither is `\xleftarrow{\sim}`.

Answer (score 4):

You can choose among various possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$f_{\mathcal{C}} \overset{\sim}{\leftarrow} f$

$f_{\mathcal{C}} \xleftarrow{\sim} f$

$f_{\mathcal{C}} \mathrel{\,\tilde{\!\leftarrow}} f$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Take your pick. The less prominent seems the last one. If you choose it, you should better make a new command:

```
\newcommand{\leftarrowsim}{\mathrel{\,\tilde{\!\leftarrow}}}
```

and use

```
$f_{\mathcal{C}} \leftarrowsim f$
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to `smash` the arrow to get better vertical spacing. You can adjust `0.4ex` to get more or less vertical space.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\isofrom{\stackrel{\sim}{\smash{\longleftarrow}\rule{0pt}{0.4ex}}}

\begin{document}

$f_{\mathcal{C}} \isofrom f$

\end{document}
```